# Get trace like console.error() with producing an error message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I do `console.error('Custom Error')` I get a nice trace of where it came from

For Example:

```
func1();

function func1() {
  func2();
}

function func2() {
  func3();
}

function func3() {
  console.error('Custom Error');
}
```

I get:

[image: JS Custom Error]

How can I do this without producing an error, more like `console.log()`?

Comment: Can I ask what your use case is? Are you writing a logger of some sort?

Comment: @ggorlen I'm using a proxy to detect the change of property and call a function to update something. I'm using `console.error` so I can see exactly where this property was changed in the code for better debugging. Since its not an error, I'd like it not to appear as one if possible

Comment: @ggorlen prefect should have thought about that. It worked great, just have a fake error for it to catch as it won't catch `console.error()`

Comment: Ah, OK, then `console.log(Error("Custom Error"))` seems like the way to go. No need to throw it and catch in the global scope as I suggested or anything like that.

Comment: @ggorlen That worked even better, there probably is not a way to remove the `Error: ` from  `Error: Custom Error` is there?

Comment: Sure, maybe `console.log(Error().stack.slice(6))`? Even better: `console.trace("foo")`

Comment: @ggorlen If you post an answer I can accept it, ty for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace) instead of [`console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error).

This is what you see on the console with `console.trace()`:

```
Trace
func3 @ js:24
func2 @ js:19
func1 @ js:15
(anonymous) @ js:12
```

And this with `console.error()`:

```
Custom Error
console.error   @   snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1:1
func3   @   js:23
func2   @   js:19
func1   @   js:15
(anonymous) @   js:12
```

If you want to get the stack trace into a variable instead of just logging it, you can use [`Error.captureStackTrace(targetObject)`](https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api) or [`Error().stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack), but both are non-standard:

```js
func1();

function func1() {
  func2();
}

function func2() {
  func3();
}

function func3() {
  const fakeErrorObject = {};
  
  Error.captureStackTrace(fakeErrorObject)
  
  const captureStackTraceTrace = fakeErrorObject.stack;
  const errorStackTrace = Error('Foo').stack;
  
  console.log(captureStackTraceTrace.replaceAll('at', ''));
  console.log(errorStackTrace.replaceAll('at', ''));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```